# How do I use a color variable in my SCSS color map in another SCSS file?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a shade of blue defined in a SCSS color map that I would like to use in a separate file. I am unsure of what the syntax is.

Here is the SCSS code:

```
$dm-blue: (
        "link":     #4EA0F9,
        "link-active":   #2FB0E1,
);
```

Here is the place in the other SCSS file that I would like to use the link-active shade.

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #2FB0E1;
```

I'd like to replace the #2FB0E1 with the link-active. What is the exact syntax to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
border-bottom: 1px solid map-get($dm-blue, "link-active");
```

[map-get documentation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#map_get-instance_method).